# How To Make Height Of Two Div Equal Respective To Each Other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I have two bootstrap panel inside class row.
And I am trying to make the height both the panel equal respective to each other even if any amount of data in placed inside the `<div class="panel-body"></div>` of any panel.
Below is my html

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
                <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
                <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default col">
                <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.

                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div><br><br>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: This might help --> http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Comment: should the height be respected even when the blocks are displayed vertically (as happens when the screen size shrinks horizontally)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use [matchHeight.js](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height#install) in this scenario.

You are able to match any component you want.

I have matched `panel-body` as that's what's increasing when you add content to it. Here's a **[pen](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/vWyrYx)** as well.

**NOTE**: As the size shrinks, this property will not be applied.
Though according to me it will be unnecessary scrolling if the property is still existing. As the user will have to scroll all the blank spaces.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.panel-body').matchHeight();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.7.0/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>
<div class="row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
      <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default col sec">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body col">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.

      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div><br><br>
```

Comment: note that the new height isn't respected when the blocks are displayed vertically (as happens when the screen size shrinks horizontally). in most scenarios, i would consider this the intended behavior, but it may be worth mentioning.

Comment: @Dhaval Jardosh : Thank you worked as expected. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `row-eq-height` to the `row` class. This will make all the panels in the row equal to the tallest one.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/m7jyh1ex/

Comment: This is a good solution as well, now I know something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write simple JS to get max computed height and assign it to all div's. You don't need jQuery.

```js
var panels = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-body');

var maxHeight = Array.prototype.map.call(panels, function(panel) {
    return parseInt(getComputedStyle(panel).height, 10);
  })
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  });

for (var i = panels.length; i-- > 0;) {
  panels[i].style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
      <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default col">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```